# How to implement PDF functionality in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am new in zend framework. I want to print my dynamic content from database in PDF. But i don't know how to implement pdf functionality in zend framework.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

here i am posting simple example to generate pdf

Let’s begin with a simple example that illustrates Zend_Pdf in action:

```
<?php
// include auto-loader class
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

// register auto-loader
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

try {
  // create PDF
  $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

  // create A4 page
  $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);

  // define font resource
  $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);

  // set font for page
  // write text to page
  $page->setFont($font, 24)
       ->drawText('That which we call a rose,', 72, 720)
       ->drawText('By any other name would smell as sweet.', 72, 620);

  // add page to document
  $pdf->pages[] = $page;

  // save as file
  $pdf->save('example.pdf');
  echo 'SUCCESS: Document saved!';
} catch (Zend_Pdf_Exception $e) {
  die ('PDF error: ' . $e->getMessage());  
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die ('Application error: ' . $e->getMessage());    
}
?>
```

let me know if i can help you more.